# How are bayesian probabilities represented in a probability space?

Tags: probability, bayesian

Given that bayesian probabilites are updated over time, how is this represented in a probability space? More specifically, how do we interpret the probability measure of such a space? That is, presumably such a probability measure is not preserved over time, whereas in frequentist statistics this is assumed to be invariant, so is a bayesian probability measure 'time-varying'?

Comment: In a frequentist world, if you take another sample, then you get other estimates, isn't that the same ?

Comment: There really are no "Bayesian" probabilities, so I'm not sure what you mean.  The term is just used to refer to a certain interpretation of probability, but the mathematics does not change in any way.

Comment: You may be interested in checking more general thread: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173056/how-exactly-do-bayesians-define-or-interpret-probability/237772#237772